# How to implement the "parent-to-child" navigational transition as prescribed by Material Design

Tags: android, material-design

Google's Material Design guidelines prescribe the following transition for "parent-to-child" transitions when the parent consists of a list.  [(Material Design Guidelines)](https://material.io/design/navigation/navigation-transitions.html#hierarchical-transitions)

How do I provide such a transition? I'm unaware of any inbuilt transition provided to make this possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I think I'm a few weeks late, but I just released a library for building this, inspired by Google Inbox: https://github.com/saket/InboxRecyclerView

Comment: Glad to be able to mark an accepted answer so many years later - only solution that understands and handles all the complexity of the transition.

Answer (score 11):

One option is to use `ActivityOptionsCompat.makeScaleUpAnimation`

```
Activity activity = getActivity();
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, OtherActivity.class);
Bundle options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeScaleUpAnimation(
    sourceView, 0, 0, sourceView.getWidth(), sourceView.getHeight()).toBundle();

ActivityCompat.startActivity(activity, intent, options);
```

This will cause the new activity to expand vertically and horizontally outwards from your `sourceView`

Comment: How to reverse it, I mean how to apply when back button pressed?

Comment: And how to adjust speed?

Answer (score 3):

Start an activity with a shared element

To make a screen transition animation between two activities that have a shared element:

Enable window content transitions in your theme.
Specify a shared elements transition in your style.
Define your transition as an XML resource.
Assign a common name to the shared elements in both layouts with the ***android:transitionName*** attribute.
Use the ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation() method.

```
// get the element that receives the click event
final View imgContainerView = findViewById(R.id.img_container);

// get the common element for the transition in this activity
final View androidRobotView = findViewById(R.id.image_small);

// define a click listener
imgContainerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
        // create the transition animation - the images in the layouts
        // of both activities are defined with android:transitionName="robot"
        ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions
            .makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, androidRobotView, "robot");
        // start the new activity
        startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
    }
});
```

For shared dynamic views that you generate in your code, use the View.setTransitionName() method to specify a common element name in both activities.

To reverse the scene transition animation when you finish the second activity, call the Activity.finishAfterTransition() method instead of Activity.finish().

Take from here [Customize Activity Transitions](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Transitions)

Answer (score 0):

you can animation using below code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NFCTagInformationActivity.class);
Bundle options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeClipRevealAnimation(
            cvTagInfoSmall, 0, 0, cvTagInfoSmall.getWidth(), cvTagInfoSmall.getHeight()).toBundle();
ActivityCompat.startActivity(this, intent, options);
```

you can use `makeScaleUpAnimation` instead of `makeClipRevealAnimation` for different view transition animation.