# How can I implement a navigation transition "Parent to Child" from a ListView?

Tags: android, android-transitions

Google's Material design documentation specifies this navigation pattern (Parent-to-child transition animation), how can I start? There is a proposal using the makeSceneTransitionAnimation of ActivityOptions class, thus I don't know if it's a right solution. Are there other alternatives? or some library?

http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigational-transitions.html

Comment: You need to give us a lot more info-  what exactly is it you're trying to do?  When are you trying to do it?  And what have you tried, what specific part of it are you having trouble with?

Comment: The idea is if an user touches an ListView's item, the application makes a transition effect,  such as Google suggests, and, then,  it shows the item's view. The link has more information about that.

Comment: What kind of effect do you want?  "Makes a transition effect" is unanswerably broad.

Comment: Please, could you click the link? The title says Parent-to-child transition animation

Comment: ANd you need to define that.  Do you want the child to expand to fill the window?  The parent to fade out?  A picture of a wizard to appear and shout "Shazam" as he makes it change to the child?  "Parent to child transition" doesn't tell us what you actually want to see happen.

Comment: @GabeSechan yes, the idea is that child can fill the window and it hides returning to its initial position on the ListView, as the link's gif suggests. Excuse me if you haven't understood me yet. For more information, there is another user asking about this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27235173/how-to-implement-the-parent-to-child-navigational-transition-as-prescribed-by